# JQuery script that selects and hides elements based on contained text isn't working for some users

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a Chrome extension to select promoted pins (by looking for the text "Promoted") on Pinterest and hide them using CSS. Because new pins are added as you scroll, I've set the script to just refresh constantly, which seems to work fine in most cases.

That said, I've gotten a handful of emails from users saying that the extension isn't working for them. It's such a basic code and I can't figure out where the problem might be coming from.

I've made sure that the permissions are set to work on all the various pinterest domains for different countries. I've requested users send me screenshots of their feed to make sure that the ads actually has the word "Promoted", which they do. By all accounts, the code should be selecting and hiding them. And I should say on my end, the extension is working perfectly.

I tried building beta versions where the script refreshes less frequently in case that was the issue, but it doesn't seem to have fixed the problem

Here is the entire script:

`setInterval(function(RemovePins) {$("div[data-grid-item='true']:has([data-test-id='oneTapPromotedPin']), div[data-grid-item='true']:contains('Promoted')").css( "display", "none" )},1);`

This should check the page every millisecond for divs that either contains the word "Promoted," or has the data-test-id of 'oneTapPromotedPin', then hide them with css. Something in that code isn't working universally, but I can't figure out what. I'm a total novice, so I'm happy to hear the thoughts of the community on how I can make this work more efficiently and consistently.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It's a task for MutationObserver.

Comment: Cool, I'm reading up on it now. Could you elaborate? If I understand correctly, you're saying that instead of refreshing every millisecond, it would only refresh when a mutation is detected (like new pins being added to the feed). Right?